# Cordova iOS cannot read files with extended characters

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios, cordova-plugin-file

I am using the following versions.

```
iOS 16.4
cordova 11.10
cordova-ios 6.3.0 
cordova-plugin-file 7.0.0
```

The Cordova app is able to create a file named `Υμνολόγιο2015` using extended characters with the following code:

```js
window.requestFileSystem(
    window.PERSISTENT,
    0,
    function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(
            encodeURI('Υμνολόγιο2015'),
            {create: true, exclusive: false},
            function(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.createWriter(
                    function(writer) {
                        console.log('File created.');
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        console.log('Error creating file. ' + error);
                    }
                );
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log('Unable to get file entry for writing. ' + error);
            }
        );
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log('Request file system failed. ' + error);
    }
);
```

The iOS file system now contains the file with an encoded file name as follows:

```
%CE%A5%CE%BC%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%8C%CE%B3%CE%B9%CE%BF2015
```

Attempting to read this file using the original file name of `Υμνολόγιο2015` results in a file not found error `code: 1` which is `NOT_FOUND_ERR`.

```js
window.requestFileSystem(
    window.PERSISTENT,
    0,
    function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(
            'Υμνολόγιο2015',
           null,
           function(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.file(
                    function(file) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onerror = function (event) {
                            console.log(event);
                        };
                        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                            console.log(evt.target.result)
                        };
                        reader.readAsText(file);
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                );
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        );
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
);
```

When I attempt to read the file using the encoded file name I get the following error `code: 5` which is `ENCODING_ERR`. It seems the encoded file name is being encoded again.

```js
window.requestFileSystem(
    window.PERSISTENT,
    0,
    function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(
            '%CE%A5%CE%BC%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%8C%CE%B3%CE%B9%CE%BF2015',
           null,
           function(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.file(
                    function(file) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onerror = function (event) {
                            console.log(event);
                        };
                        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                            console.log(evt.target.result)
                        };
                        reader.readAsText(file);
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                );
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        );
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
);
```

If I do the same thing with a file name using only ASCII characters, writing and reading the file has no issues.

This also only happens on iOS, Android has no issues.

Thanks for your help and time!